# GRPC Okhttp android client channel with self signed ssl certificate

Tags: kotlin, ssl, grpc, grpc-java

I have a grpc-js server using self signed ssl certificates.

```js
var credentials = grpc.ServerCredentials.createSsl(
    fs.readFileSync('./node/grpc/ssl/ca.crt'), 
    [{
        cert_chain: fs.readFileSync('./node/grpc/ssl/server.crt'),
        private_key: fs.readFileSync('./node/grpc/ssl/server.key')
    }], 
    true
);
```

I then tested this setup with a grpc-js client with the following credential setup and this works.

```js
var credentials = grpc.credentials.createSsl(
    fs.readFileSync('./node/grpc/ssl/ca.crt'),
    fs.readFileSync('./node/grpc/ssl/client.key'),
    fs.readFileSync('./node/grpc/ssl/client.crt')
);
```

I want to replicate this in Android using OkHttpChannelBuilder but it is a bit more complicated. This is what I have so far.

```kotlin
private val mChannel : ManagedChannel
init {
    /**
     * Server certificate to make it trusted.
     */
    val serverCrtFile = applicationContext.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.server)
    val serverCertificate: X509Certificate =
        CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(serverCrtFile) as X509Certificate

    val caKeyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()).apply {
        load(null, null)
        setCertificateEntry("server", serverCertificate)
    }

    val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()).apply {
        init(caKeyStore)
    }

    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS").apply {
        init(null, trustManagerFactory.trustManagers, null)
    }

    mChannel = OkHttpChannelBuilder
        .forAddress(BuildConfig.GRPC_HOST_ADDRESS, BuildConfig.GRPC_HOST_PORT)
        .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory)
        .keepAliveTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .useTransportSecurity()
        .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
        .build()
}
```

Everything worked before implementing ssl (so using `plaintext()` on the channel builder).

The error I get now is `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: End of stream or IOException`.
Can someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong and how I can get a successful connection like between the js server and client.

Comment: So I can set the third parameter on the server's `grpc.ServerCredentials.createSsl()` function to `false`. This parameter specifies if the client certificate needs to be verified by the server.
I would still like some help on how to setup the client certificate on Android, please.

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace? Also, does the server require mutual TLS? Looks it does as the grpc-js client also takes in client cert/key. In that case, you would need two KeyStores, one for client cert/key and one for CA cert. Then create a KeyManagerFactory inited with the KeyStore for client cert/key. Finally, init the SSLContext with KeyManagers getting from the factory. 

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/6374#issuecomment-550166965 contains the complete code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the SSL handshake failed on the server side so it will be helpful to get server side detailed logs to see what went wrong.

One possibility is using `KeyStore.getInstance`. Can you try using `"PKCS12"`?

```
 KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
```